# Conditional passing down props to child components in vuejs2

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-component

My html code===>

```
<email-consent inline-template
           :submit-queue="saveForLaterMethods">

</email-consent>
```

I want to pass **saveForLaterMethods** if it is defined.

I also try with this code

```
saveForLaterMethods? saveForLaterMethods : undefined
```

But every time I get this console log error.

> Property or method "saveForLaterMethods" is not defined on the
>   instance but referenced during render. Make sure that this property is
>   reactive

Is there any way to check **undefined** in html?

Answer (score 0):

Check if it is defined:

```
:submit-queue="typeof saveForLaterMethods != 'undefined' ? saveForLaterMethods : undefined"
```

Comment: still getting vue js warning.

Comment: is it listed in the props?

Comment: Which one? I don't get it

Comment: is `saveForLaterMethods` listed as an expected prop of the component like `props:  ['saveForLaterMethods']`

Comment: Isn't it 'submitQueue'?

Comment: This is how you pass it to the child saveForLaterMethods should be defined in the current component either as a prop or in the data